# What happened to the htdocs folder from Apache?

Tags: mysql, apache, tomcat, phpmyadmin

I have scoured the internet for the answer to this, so I thought I would open up the question here.  I have installed Apache Tomcat and MySQL.  I now want to install phpmyadmin to work with my mySQL Database.  All instructions say to install phpmyadmin in the "htdocs" folder that resides in the Apache folder.  I have tried installing and reinstalling Apache a number of times, and none of the installations come with a htdocs folder.  Does anyone know why, where it is, or how I can install phpmyadmin without it?  Can I just create a folder called htdocs, or is there something important in there I am missing?

Comment: Look for the document root in httpd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is a JSP server. For Java apps, not PHP. I think you want to download and install the regular Apache and not Apache Tomcat.

http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: Jordan - I am developing a jsp web app, so I do want Tomcat.  I just want to use phpmyadmin to access my database.  Not sure how to install phpmyadmin without the htdocs folder, or why there is no htdocs folder with the install of Apache Tomcat in the first place.

Comment: Hm.. Okay. Maybe this would help you out? Link: http://technonstop.com/run-phpmyadmin-alongside-tomcat-webapps

Comment: Well Jordan, your original answer was close to being right.  Apparently I wanted both the regular apache, which has the htdocs folder so I can run phpMyAdmin to access my database, and Tomcat as my jsp server.  I installed xampp and Tomcat.  Thank you for looking in to this.  I'm a newbie and didn't realize there was a difference between the "regular apache" and Tomcat.

Comment: Good deal. Can you mark my response as the correct answer? Thanks!